# Where to ask psychiatry questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

In which community can I ask about Psychiatry?

I can see it's not in the [Health](https://health.stackexchange.com) community.

Example question: "How to stop doing {some bad habit}?"

Answer (score 5):

If you have a question about the science of psychiatric study, it can be asked on [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/).

> Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry.

I strongly recommend that you review their [on topic](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, though, as questions asking for personal psychiatric help are *not* welcome there.

In your specific case, I don't know that there's a good site for you. If it's a habit like [nail biting](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10731/how-to-stop-biting-my-nails) that may have a practical (rather than mental) solution, you might find some help over on [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) but be aware that their [help page](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) reads:

> If your question is ***NOT* about** [. . . ] "mind hacks" including personal productivity & self-improvement tips, memorization & learning techniques, etc [. . .] …then you are in the right place.

So, what your habit is and what sort of solution you're looking for will determine whether it's a good fit for them or not.

A third option. If you're asking about habits as they relate to your ability to do work, your question might be on topic on our [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) site. They have several questions under the [habits](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/habit) tag and I invite you to look over them to see if they might meet your needs. Please keep in mind the purpose of that site is:

> Personal Productivity Stack Exchange is for people wanting to improve their personal productivity. If you have a question about...
>
> - achieving a productivity workflow, using techniques like GTD, Covey, Pomodoro, etc.
> - fighting procrastination by getting energetic and motivated
>     workflow
> - ergonomics
> - effective sleep habits and the entire sleep-wake transition
> - learning, memory and creativity
>
> ... then you are in the right place.

Comment: It's personal, what should i do?

Comment: I edited it, please check.

Comment: @Catija Somehow didn't notice you posted a link. Pppf. That double standard. Was closed as offtopic, not a dupe. Was essentially the same question.

Comment: @Catija Mm. I think I may have worded it just different enough from the post you linked to to violate that. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

[Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) would be the best place to ask.

> Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for practitioners, researchers, and students in cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry.

More specific, questions on psychiatry under the [psychiatry](/questions/tagged/psychiatry) tag [here](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychiatry). Questions relating to habits may be considered self-help which is not allowed so it all depends on the context of the question. Below you can see a list of the things you can and can't ask on their website.

[image: Cognitive Sciences Stack Exchange Tour excerpt]